# Symmetric-key encryption algorithm

Tags: java, javascript, encryption

I'm looking for a secure symmetric-key encryption algorithm compatible with both JavaScript and Java.

I've tried implementing one but I had some encoding issues.

Comment: What do you mean with "compatible"?

Comment: So I can encrypt with JavaScript and decrypt with Java and vice versa with no encoding issues.

Comment: I would like to recommend you to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: It has to do with encoding and it is a good read. It does not matter if you encrypt something with Java, JavaScript, Python etc. and decrypt it with .Net, Ruby etc.

Comment: What issues did you run into?

Comment: @NayukiMinase I was able to encrypt and decrypt correctly on both JavaScript and Java but when I tried to encrypt in JavaScript and decrypt in Java and vice versa some texts weren't decrypted correctly.

Comment: Is using just HTTPS or communication over SSL not sufficient for you? I guess you wanted to avoid MITM Attack.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't want to encrypt with JavaScript, [especially on the client-side where it is open to tampering](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/why-do-some-people-really-hate-security-via-client-side), and has no [cryptographically secure random number generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key).

> I've tried implementing one but I had some encoding issues.

You tried to write your own encryption algo? You've gone against everything that the security world hold dear.  No. Actual tutorials that explain how encryption works are so scared that people are going to screw things up because they don't understand the math behind it, I've actually seen this in one of them:

[image]

If you don't understand encryption, things like, what "cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator" actually is, and common attacks on it, you shouldn't do that.

If you don't understand things like side-channel attacks, you shouldn't do it.

If you don't understand what's going on in crypto and have read at-least two books on it you have no business implementing it.

**Crypto is not a magic black box, it's something that is very VERY easy to screw up, even without touching any bit of code in a packaged solution.**

What *should* you do? Forget about JS encryption. I know, I've tried it myself. It's a waste of time. Learn from my mistakes.

Go get an SSL certificate, SSL is the best way for us to encrypt messages on the transport level from a server to a client. It's about as secure as you can get. If you face an advesary that can defeat SSL, trust me, your JS-based crypto is also compromised.

Once it's at the server where it's secure from being tampered with, encrypt it. Anything else is a really long way to waste your time.

Also, go read these books:

[![This one is free][4]](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)


[[![This one is cash money][5]][5]  
<sub>(source: [schneier.com](https://www.schneier.com/images/book-ce-150w.jpg))</sub>](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography-engineering)

Then when you understand them come back and scream at me about why I'm wrong and don't understand how much you need JS on the client to do crypto.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent DES (and by extension 3DES) implementation in JS, which I use quite often. I'll put up the link Monday, when I'm at the office and have it ready. Results from this (after base64 encoding for the transport) work perfectly with .Net/Mono (builtin), Java (bulitin) and PHP (mcrypt).

Found the links, but both are dead: http://www.shopable.co.uk/des.html and http://www.netdealing.com. I have put it up on http://pastebin.com/KbRsWKJY

Comment: Mhh at university they taught me that DES now it's easily decriptable... AES should be ok, but I don't think javascript can handle such a thing.

Comment: DES is easily decipherable because of brute force attacks, but DESede isn't easily decipherable. AES is a *faster* implementation than DESede, so if JavaScript can handle DESede, it can certainly handle AES-128. Use DESede only for legacy implementations (or, if you cannot find another library and understand the few weaknesses such as small block size, weak keys, parity bits in keys etc.).

Comment: Let me clarify: Pointing to the JS Code doesn't mean, that I embrace the unreflected usage of (3)DES on the client side uncritically. But I consider it a fact, that using JS cryptography can be a meaningfull layer in defense.in-depth. So I use it, where I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html) has CTR mode, which is available in Java. I would recommend keys of 128 bits or you might run into trouble regarding the Java export policies on larger key sizes.

[Here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) is a page which uses some very usefull methods of encryption, including password encryption techniques and ciphres with integrity checks and authentication, although you may need the bouncy castle libraries on Java to match those all.

There are oodles of libraries for JavaScript, but character encoding issues will be present on any of them. So make sure you use the same encoding both on the JavaScript side as well as on the Java side. A quick look up assures me that JavaScript uses UTF-16 internally, but don't hang me up on that.

Finally, don't try this at home, the libraries are there, use them (especially if they mention tests and/or official test vectors).

Comment: Where can I find Java implementation of AES that uses Bouncy Caste?

Comment: Bouncy Castle libraries implement a JCE/JCA provider. So most of the functionality is added to the crypto API of Java itself. You can access the bouncy implementation by using e.g. Cipher.getInstance("algo/mode/padding", "BC"); but only *after* you have added the provider to the Security class. You can also directly access the lower level BC implementation of security functions directly.

Comment: Are there two examples compatible?
JavaScript: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html;
Java: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html

Comment: Nah, "AES" in Java translates into "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding". You will need "AES/CTR/NoPadding".

Comment: I tried using BouncyCastle to decrypt the message and after looking at a couple of examples, I made this method http://ideone.com/s4XQV (based on a TEA algorithm method) but I keep getting the following exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers said, if you don't have to encrypt with JavaScript, avoid it. However, there are some valid use cases to encrypting in JavaScript.

When you need to, I recommend this library: https://keybase.io/triplesec/.

It's more secure than DES, which another answer links to.